# Implement a stored procedure with conditions and update

Tags: sql-server

The objective here is to update the table: BOOK_LOANS, column: @Status to a string  (See code below) when  I execute the Stored procedure. When the loan time goes past the Due_date adds 1 @Warning to the table READERS. When @Warnings = 3, SET @Eligibility to 'NOT ELIGIBLE'. How can I write this, this syntax is a mess.

```
IF SELECT DATEDIFF(day, @Due_date, CONVERT(date, getdate())) = 5
    BEGIN
        UPDATE BOOK_LOANS
        SET @Status = 'DELAYED'
        RETURN;
    END

    IF DATEDIFF(day, @Due_date, CONVERT(date, getdate())) = 3
    BEGIN
        UPDATE BOOK_LOANS
        SET @Status = 'URGENT RETURN'
        RETURN;
    END
    
    IF DATEDIFF(day, @Due_date, CONVERT(date, getdate())) = -1
    BEGIN
        UPDATE BOOK_LOANS
        SET @Status = 'OUTDATED'
        UPDATE READERS
        SET @Warnings = @Warnings + 1
        RETURN;
    END
    
    IF (@Warnings > 3) 
    BEGIN
    UPDATE READERS
    SET @Eligibility = 'NOT ELIGIBLE'
    END
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do from this code. I doubt that you want to update the entire table based on one record, which is what this code appears to attempt to do but fails because `@Status` is a variable rather than a column name.

Comment: The syntax is wrong but I can't get it right. Ok, first error. That should be a column name.
I want to update the whole column Status if Due_date is not NULL and if the time difference between the Due_date and NOW is either 5, 3 or -1. -1 Means the user who didn't return the book from the table READERS will receive a Warning.

Comment: But WHICH ROW do you want to change? Currently your code updates EVERY ROW in the table.

Comment: Every row for that column should be affected if Due_date is NOT NULL and the difference with NOW is either 5, 3 or -1. Thats a simple reminder of the status of the loan that will only have real implications if he goes past Due_date that will update TABLE READERS COLUMN WARNINGS to Warnings + 1

Comment: When your code generates an error, it is pointless to write something like "doesn't work" or "can't implement" or "it's wrong". Post the complete error message - all of it. In addition, post the entire stored procedure, not just a fragment. But it seems you don't understand what RETURN does. It works like every other language, exiting a "block" of code and returning execution to the caller of the "block". That last block of posted code is never reached if any of the preceding IF statements are true.

Comment: And statements like `UPDATE READERS SET @Warnings = @Warnings + 1` do nothing to the contents of the table. You should get guidance from your teammates, coworkers, fellow students, manager, etc. You need more basic tsql skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for the time. After some time learning a lit bit more I came to this final code. For some reason I couldn't apply the code above but nevertheless helped me to reach my final code.

```
UPDATE book_loans
SET    loan_status = CASE
                       WHEN Datediff(day, CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()), due_date) =
                            5 THEN
                       'RETURN SOON'
                       WHEN Datediff(day, CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()), due_date) =
                            3 THEN
                       'URGENT RETURN'
                       WHEN Datediff(day, CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()), due_date) <=
                            -1
                            THEN 'OUTDATED'
                       ELSE loan_status
                     END;

-- Create temp table
SELECT r.card_no,
       b.due_date,
       Warnings = 0
INTO   #temp3
FROM   readers AS r
       JOIN book_loans AS b
         ON r.card_no = b.card_no

SELECT *
FROM   #temp3

-- Calculate warnings 
UPDATE #temp3
SET    warnings = CASE
                    WHEN Datediff(day, CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()), due_date) <= -1
                  THEN
                    warnings + 1
                    ELSE warnings
                  END;

UPDATE readers
SET    readers.warnings = readers.warnings + p.total
FROM   (SELECT card_no,
               Sum(warnings) AS total
        FROM   #temp3
        GROUP  BY card_no) p
WHERE  readers.card_no = p.card_no

UPDATE readers
SET    eligibility = CASE
                       WHEN warnings > 3 THEN 'NOT ELIGIBLE'
                       ELSE eligibility
                     END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here is what you are trying to do :

```
UPDATE BOOK_LOANS
SET 
 status = CASE DATEDIFF(day, Due_date, CONVERT(date, getdate())) 
              WHEN 5 THEN 'DELAYED'
              WHEN 3 THEN 'URGENT RETURN'
              WHEN -1 THEN 'OUTDATED'
              ELSE status
          END
, warning = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, Due_date, CONVERT(date, getdate())) = -1 
                 THEN warning + 1 
                 ELSE warning
           END
GO
UPDATE r
SET Eligibility = CASE WHEN l.warning > 3 
                       THEN 'NOT ELIGIBLE' 
                       ELSE Eligibility 
                  END
FROM  READERS r
JOIN BOOK_LOANS l
 on l.reader_id = l.reader_is -- here I assume you need to link two tables based on the PK, FKs
```